# How do you change the LDAP DN for a user?

Tags: 6, users, authentication-authorization

We are using LDAP integration on a Drupal 6 system (with the "LDAP authentication" module).

During initial log-in, the user account will be created and the DN (Distinguished Name) for that user will be set automatically.

Now, due to some structural changes, the DN for some users will change slightly.

Is it possible to somehow change the DN that is used by Drupal, or to force some kind of "re-authentication" of Drupal Usernames with the Active Directory? Or do I have to edit the ldap_dn in the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If memory serves me the DN will get auto updated next time they log in.  No editing necessary.